# What is the area of law for procedures setting out the legislative process called and what theory is there?

Tags: legislature

Some laws act to explicitly set out what constitutes a law change, what types of legislation are possible and the legislative process that must be followed to enact a law. What is the area of law under which these are classified and is there any prominent philosophy or legal theory on these types of rules? On the philosophy side I have read some formal work but I am looking for more informal research.

Note that, I am talking about rules that are definitional, defining what constitutes rule change. As opposed to what rule change should take place. I initially thought administrative law covered this area, but it appears not.

Some examples:

"No Bill of Attainder or ex post facto Law shall be passed" - United States Constitution. Here it refers to the type of law that can be passed.

"If a Money Bill, having been passed by the House of Commons, and sent up to the House of Lords at least one month before the end of the session, is not passed by the House of Lords without amendment within one month after it is so sent up to that House, the Bill shall, unless the House of Commons direct to the contrary, be presented to His Majesty and become an Act of Parliament on the Royal Assent being signified, notwithstanding that the House of Lords have not consented to the Bill." - Parliament Acts of the United Kingdom

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's called constitutional law; even in countries with no *written* constitution like the UK.

The administrative rules and procedures are called parliamentary (or congressional) procedure.

Comment: Also, Administrative Law.